# Reconnect links on force graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm new in d3.js and I'm trying to do the next thing in the force graph - reconnect paths between nodes. Since the image.

[image]

So I can to drag the red circle and path connected to other node or moved on other point on this shape contour(like connector in Visio). Is it possible? I didn't find such examples.

Sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
call(force.drag);
```

for red-circles and you can drag them.it generates a new path again after the drag call

Comment: Ок, but I don't understand - for the red circles I should write .data(nodes) or .data(links)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example [link1](https://483bca3012c61392ca086e7377bfedd1d28040ea.googledrive.com/host/0B0XBTG9h5S15Q1pibDhWNmFjQ1E/) in which the drag call is called only for the circles.
Here is the second example [link2](https://71ef85ca2d31942b68b72d581c634b0d06153942.googledrive.com/host/0B0XBTG9h5S15UW1sbHVkbGhCT0k/) in which the drag call is called only for the circles and the links means you can drag both links and circles.So if you want both links and circles to respond to drag you can add to both of them.

Comment: [Example here](http://bl.ocks.org/hunzy/9929724).you can see how the path of the circle is been given.